# Generate correlation matrix with specific columns and only with significant values in corrplot

Tags: r, correlation, p-value, r-corrplot

I have a data.frame database with 14 columns. I split these columns into two groups: `[,1:6] and [,7:14]`.

```
df<-read.csv("http://renatabrandt.github.io/EBC2015/data/varechem.csv", row.names=1)

df
```

I would like to calculate the correlation between these two groups of columns.
For that I used this command and it worked very well:

```
#I want to correlate columns [1:6] with [7:14] only.
correlation_df<-cor(df[,1:6],
                    df[,7:14], method="spearman", use="pairwise.complete.obs")

# graph correlation specific columns
corrplot(correlation_df,
         method="color", addCoef.col = "black")
```

[image]

However, in addition to calculating the correlation, I would like the graph to show only the significant correlations (p-value<0.05).
I tried the following code but it didn't work because the view was wrong.

```
#I can get the significance level matrix
correlation_df_sig<-cor.mtest(df, conf.level = 0.95, method = "spearman")
correlation_df_sig
```

#Generate correlation matrix only with significant values

```
plot2<-corrplot(correlation_df,
         p.mat = correlation_df_sig$p,
         insig='blank',
         addCoef.col = "black")
plot2
```

[image]

What could I do to fix this view?

OBS:
I tried to generate a complete array without considering the `[,1:6] and [,7:14]` groups, but it also went wrong. Also, I don't want to calculate the correlation between columns in the same group. Ex: column 1 with column 2, column 1 with column 3...

```
plot1<-corrplot(cor(df, method = 'spearman', use = "pairwise.complete.obs"),
         method = 'color', 
         addCoef.col = 'black',
         p.mat = correlation_df_sig$p,
         insig='blank',
         diag = FALSE,
         number.cex = 0.5,
         type='upper'
         )
plot1
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your calculation, shouldn't you do `cor(df)[1:6, 7:14]`?

Comment: yes I could, but how to show only the significant values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the well established `Hmisc::rcorr` for the calculations. In `corrplot::corrplot`, subset both the `corr=` and the `p.mat=` with `[1:6, 7:14]`.

```
c_df <- Hmisc::rcorr(cor(correlation_df), type='spearman')

library(corrplot)
corrplot(corr=c_df$r[1:6, 7:14], p.mat=c_df$P[1:6, 7:14], sig.level=0.05, 
         method='color', diag=FALSE, addCoef.col=1, type='upper', insig='blank',
         number.cex=.8)
```

[image]

This appears to correspond to the p-values.

```
m <- c_df$P[1:6, 7:14] < .05
m[lower.tri(m, diag=TRUE)] <- ''
as.data.frame(replace(m, lower.tri(m, diag=TRUE), ''))
#    Al    Fe    Mn   Zn    Mo Baresoil Humdepth    pH
# N     FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE    FALSE    FALSE FALSE
# P            TRUE TRUE FALSE    FALSE    FALSE FALSE
# K                 TRUE FALSE    FALSE    FALSE  TRUE
# Ca                     FALSE     TRUE     TRUE FALSE
# Mg                               TRUE     TRUE  TRUE
# S                                        FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Hello! your answer answers exactly what the question asked. But I came across a situation where I have `nodata` or `NA` values in the data.frame. How would the `corr` function solve this? Greetings

Comment: @wesleysc352 *" Pairs with fewer than 2 non-missing values have the r values set to NA."* It is explained in the documentation, just type `help(rcorr)`, their example is also with `NA's`.

Comment: update: According to the new updated Hmisc documentation, `rcorr` by default calculates the correlation disregarding only pairs with NA, it doesn't delete the whole row, because of an NA. The new documentation can be seen here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/Hmisc.pdf